# How to copy a Stream from the begining irrespective its current position

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I got a file stream which has content read from a disk.

```
    Stream input = new FileStream("filename");
```

This stream is to be passed to a third party library which after reading the stream, keeps the Stream's position pointer at the end of the file (as ususal).

My requirement is not to load the file from the desk everytime, instead I want to maintain `MemoryStream`, which will be used everytime.

```
    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

I have tried the above code. It works for the first very time to copy the input stream to output stream, but subsequent calls to `CopyStream` will not work as the source's `Position` will be at the end of the stream after the first call.

Are there other alternatives which copy the content of the source stream to another stream irrespective of the source stream's current `Position`.

And this code needs to run in thread safe manner in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: If the stream is seekable, you can just change to position to zero (`input.Position = 0;`). Or, since you're keeping the whole file in memory anyway, don't use streams at all :)

Comment: Agreed. Although there is a danger here from a maintenance point of view. As you state, the 3rd party library moves the position because it reads the file. What else might it do in the future? You are setting up a maintenance headache here unnecessarily. The buffer you create is 32K so we are talking peanuts in terms of processing time and storage. So why not just pass a new stream every time? If you keep the data in memory as @Luaan suggested then pass a copy to the library to prevent data changes. Rule of thumb, never rely on mutable data being reusable if given to a third party library.

Comment: @JamesLucas "The buffer you create is 32K so we are talking peanuts in terms of processing time and storage." That's a temporary buffer, for copying in chunks, the file size could be more/less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the input stream's `CanSeek` property. If that returns false, you can only read it once anyway. If `CanSeek` returns true, you can set the position to zero and copy away.

```
if (input.CanSeek)
{
    input.Position = 0;
}
```

You may also want to store the old position and restore it after copying.

ETA: Passing the same instance of a `Stream` around is not the safest thing to do. E.g. you can't be sure the `Stream` wasn't disposed when you get it back. I'd suggest to copy the `FileStream` to a `MemoryStream` in the beginning, but only store the byte content of the latter by calling `ToArray()`. When you need to pass a `Stream` somewhere, just create a new one each time with `new MemoryStream(byte[])`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .NET 4.0 [Stream.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.Stream.CopyTo);k(CopyTo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)  to copy your steam to a MemoryStream. The MemoryStream has a Position property you can use to move its postition to the beginning.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(@"filename"))
{
   file.CopyTo(ms);
}
ms.Position = 0;
```

To make a thread safe solution, you can copy the content to a byte array, and make a new MemoryStream wrapping the byte array for each thread that need access:

```
byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
var ms2 = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
```